# How to patch .NET dll to the GAC using InstallShield QuickPatch?

Tags: installshield, patch

I'm trying to patch a .NET DLL file using the Quick Patch project of InstallShield. The DLL needs to be registered for COM Interoperation.

When I patch the file, the dll seems to be replaced correctly in the GAC, but when I try to access it from my application I get an error indicating that the application cannot connect to the DLL.

I think that it is not being registered properly for COM interop, but I'm not sure about it.

Any idea of what should I do to make it work?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you set the ".NET COM Interop" attribute on the component to Yes?

Comment: Yes I did set the .NET COM Interop attribute to yes. During a clean installation the DLL is properly registered to the GAC and available for COM Interop. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to run regasm(it's in .NET framework directory) with correct params to register for com interop.  Also the DLL file is usually built with certain COM visible options selected.  Been a long time since I dealt with that nightmare though, so can't remember all the details.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Thanks. the DLL is built with the COM Interop settings, but I wouldn't like to use any external tool at this point, and besides that I'm not sure it's possible to add a new custom action using a Quick Patch project.